# How can I add required attribute?

Tags: django

I would like to add the `required` attribute in the ***product_title*** field. How can I do It?

```
class add_product_info(forms.ModelForm):
    product_desc = RichTextField()

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ('product_title')

        labels = {'product_title':'Title'}

        widgets = {
            'product_title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'style':'font-size:13px;'})
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the same way like you added the `style` or `class` attribute:

```py
class add_product_info(forms.ModelForm):
    product_desc = RichTextField()

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ('product_title')
        labels = {'product_title':'Title'}
        widgets = {
            'product_title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'style':'font-size:13px;', 'required': True})
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `required` in the field specifications. This will also enforce this at form level, so the Django form will reject the form in case the field is not filled in:

```
class ProductInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    product_desc = RichTextField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Products
        fields = ('product_title',)
        labels = {'product_title':'Title'}
        widgets = {
            'product_title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'style':'font-size:13px;'})
        }
```

---

> **Note**: Forms in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`add_product_info`</s> to `ProductInfoForm`.

Answer (score 2):

You can slightly manipulate existing fields in `__init__` method. In this way you can automatically add that attribute.

```
class BaseForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for bound_field in self:
            if hasattr(bound_field, "field") and bound_field.field.required:
                bound_field.field.widget.attrs["required"] = "required"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add to your template you can use django widget tweaks

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<!-- add 2 extra css classes to field element -->
{{ form.title|append_attr:"class:css_class_1 css_class_2" }}
```

[django_widget_tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/)